# Prove/Disprove: Properties Of Cyclic Subgroups

Tags: group-theory, proof-verification

> Prove/Disprove:
>
> 1. Every subgroup generated by one element is cyclic
> 2. If $o(a)=n$ so $a^{-1}=a^{n-1}$

1. By definition a group is cyclic if for an element $a\in G$ , $\langle a \rangle=G$ (it can be one or more elements, in particular one element)
2. By definition $a^{0(a)}=e$ because $a\in G$ is a group there is $a^{-1}\in G$ and $G$ is closed under the operation
   So $$a^{0(a)}=e\iff a^{n}=e$$
   Multiply both sides by $a^{-1}$

$$a^{n}\cdot a^{-1}=e\cdot a^{-1}\iff a^{n-1}=a^{-1}$$

> Are the proofs valid?

Comment: I think they are true.

Comment: I'm the \langle \rangle fairy, here to let you know that $\langle, \rangle$ plays nicer with TeX than $<, >$ does :)

Comment: Both are correct.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you're correct.

The

> $$a^{0(a)}=e\iff a^{n}=e$$

bit is somewhat unnecessary, however.

It could be more rigorous if you referenced the lemma that is the law of indices you used at the end too. That's somewhat pedantic though.